# What to do when another user copies your answer?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I tried to answer a question, and after a while another user gives almost exactly the same answer. What is the purpose of this? Why do other users replicate an answer? Is it normal that every question is answered multiple times with the same answer? Isn't that redundancy?

According to SE policy, posts should be improved by comments or edits, not by copying? On other SE sites I have never seen this.

[Gene density percentage](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68069/gene-density-percentage)

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea behind the stack network is to generate multiple answers such that the best is voted to the top.

Having said that, Remi.b's answer is indeed somewhat of a duplicate answer. But in this case, given the question is kind of a facts question, generating a second answer can only be realized by duping prior ones, as the only correct answer is 85% = ORF = protein -- 15% = regulatory. If another users wishes to add another answer, it can't be left out or substituted because then the answer is incorrect. The only thing that can be added are additional sources (that's what Remi.b did) or add additional information, backgrounds or images.

In all, I think the answer is kind of a dupe, but reasonable given the type of question.

Of course they could have opted to comment below yours to generate a better answer out of yours, but that's not a hard rule.

Comment: de novo? Are you serious? Even my examples are copied literally in same order (regulatory, repeats, or other). Well, it seems a bit political here on this SE site, maybe I should start a question here asking how to get out of a waps nest...

Comment: @b.nota why did you delete your answer? With an added source I'm happy to upvote it and remove that banner. Multiple answers are encouraged. It's not a matter of the best one survives you know.

Comment: The "source" given in Remi's answer actually has nothing to do with the answer to the question. Additionally, it is not a reference to scientific literature or even a text book but rather is a video by someone of indeterminate knowledge. I really don't in understand the logic behind saying b.nota's answer requires sources whereas Remi's does not.

Comment: @canadianer wow big oops there. Thanks. I've adapted my answer here. I'll check those links the next time. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thanks @canadianer, I didn't understand either why a link to central dogma would help OP. As if someone that asks how to calculate % of genic in genome doesn't now what central dogma is...

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I don't think duplicate answers are helpful. If Remi.D wants more rep. its all his.

Comment: @b.nota I see where you are heading at. The problem is that your answer is not the suspected dupe, but Remi's is. I'd rather see your answer out there. FWIW,  Given Canadianer's comment I've removed my upvote for remi.

Comment: For me it's not about votes, I just wanted to give the OP an answer. And I am not upset, I am FURIOUS. And now I'm joking. Just leave it, I just couldn't understand why a top user is showing this behavior, that's all.

Comment: @b.nota yeah I'm sorry about all this, but I'm still happy we are having this discussion. Honestly, I wouldn't have added another answer and I would like to see your answer back up. As a mod I can do that, but I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: Haha, since this message here on meta, I recieve a -1 vote for every answer I post. There most be a lot of high school teen agers around here?

Comment: What is all this about? There is only one answer when I follow the link, which is RemiB's. I have just downvoted it for the reasons I give in my comment. If it is a copy of b.nota's he should be glad of that.

Comment: @David - OP deleted their own answer. [Here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/68078/9943) is the permalink - I am curious if it will work on your end.

Comment: @AliceD — No. It doesn't work for me. Water under the bridge anyway. Got involved in a "polite discussion" on SE English Language & Usage recently over what a mod implied was plagiarism by another poster. Area in which to tread carefully, I think.

Comment: @David - yes this one post was a minefield too and I was actually politely reprimanded by another mod. Things can turn quickly for the worse, even with the best intentions.